# Adding a multiple parameters from android to webservice

Tags: java, android, web-services, android-studio

i have this webservice:

```
   [WebMethod]
    public string AddStudent(string name)
    {

        return addSt(name);
    }

    public String addSt(String name)
    {

        SqlConnection conn;
        conn = Class1.ConnectionManager.GetConnection();
        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand newCmd = conn.CreateCommand();

        newCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        newCmd.CommandText = "insert into dbo.tblUser values('" + name + "','2')";
        SqlDataReader sdr = newCmd.ExecuteReader();

        conn.Close();
        return "successfully done";


    }
```

which add new record to my database, in the table i have id (auto-increment), name and grade.

and i have this java could which call the webservice and add the values from there:

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText editText;
private TextView textView;
private Handler mHandler= new Handler();



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
}
public void getName(View v){

    String inputId =editText.getText().toString();
    //String[] params= new String[]{"10.0.2.2",inputId};
    String[] params= new String[]{"192.168.1.17:90",inputId};
    new MyAsyncTask().execute(params);

}

class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{

    public String SOAP_ACTION="http://tempuri.org/AddStudent";
    public String OPERATION_NAME ="AddStudent";
    public String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE ="http://tempuri.org/";
    public String SOAP_ADDRESS;
    private SoapObject request;
    private HttpTransportSE httpTransport;
    private SoapSerializationEnvelope envelop;
    Object response= null;


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        SOAP_ADDRESS="http://"+params[0]+"/myWebService.asmx";
        request= new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,OPERATION_NAME);
        PropertyInfo pi=new PropertyInfo();
        pi.setName("name");
        pi.setValue(params[1]);
        pi.setType(Integer.class);
        request.addProperty(pi);
        pi= new PropertyInfo();

        envelop= new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelop.dotNet=true;
        envelop.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        httpTransport=new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
        try{
            httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION,envelop);
            response=envelop.getResponse();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            response=e.getMessage();
        }
        return response.toString();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final String result){
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                textView.setText(result);
            }
        });
    }
   }
}
```

This is adding only name, what should i change in these values:

```
   PropertyInfo pi=new PropertyInfo();
        pi.setName("name");
        pi.setValue(params[1]);
        pi.setType(Integer.class);
        request.addProperty(pi);
        pi= new PropertyInfo();
```

so i can add the name and grade from the android?

i tried adding an edit text and put its value like this:

```
        pi.setName("name","grade");
        pi.setValue(params[1],params[2]);
```

but i got errors, how to do it correctly?

also note that i know the changes that must be done in the webservice so it can add the name and grade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add as many properties to your request

```
PropertyInfo pi=new PropertyInfo();
        pi.setName("name");
        pi.setValue(params[0]);// Generally array index starts from 0 not 1
        pi.setType(Integer.class);
        request.addProperty(pi);

pi= new PropertyInfo();

pi.setName("grade");
        pi.setValue(params[1]);
        pi.setType(Integer.class);
        request.addProperty(pi);
```

Comment: THANKS ALOT!! Worked perfectly.